Best way to read in csv files in shiny with interactive prompt to select file?
I need to be able to interactively read in multiple csv files in my shiny app (i.e. the user selects the file in a prompt) and so far haven't found the holy grail, yet. This is for working locally on the user's computer, e.g. within RStudio, not on shinyapps.io or similar.
Option 1: actionbutton + file.choose()
This is the most straightforward option and would be sufficient, if the prompt wouldn't push RStudio in the foreground and the app in the background. This is a known issue that does not yet appear to have been fixed.
ui <- fluidPage(
  actionButton('getdata', 'Get Data')
)

server<-function(input, output, session) {
  
  observeEvent(input$getdata,{
    dat<-read.csv(file.choose())
  })
}

shinyApp(ui,server)

Option2: actionbutton + selectFile()
A fix to the above issue is using rstudioapi::selectFile(). However, this comes with two major limitations:

It may not work as expected on Windows. I'm on a mac, so cannot verify nor test, but need my app to run smoothly on both macs and windows PCs.
The prompt will always default to some system root path, not even the working directory. For multiple files, this requires the user a lot of browsing to the directory with the files (i.e. the working directory). This is absolutely less than ideal.

server<-function(input, output, session) {
  
  observeEvent(input$getdata,{
    dat<-read.csv(rstudioapi::selectFile())
  })
}

shinyApp(ui,server)

Option 3: fileInput()
This appears to be the most robust solution. However, it requires quite a lot of modifications to get the same optics and performance as if I was using an actionbutton (I'm also working with shinyjs::disable() and larger files etc.). Most importantly it appears to be much slower in performance. This will be particularly an issue if large files always need to be 'uploaded' to a temporary directory first before being able to even read them in.
fileInput2 <- function(..., label="") {
  temp <- fileInput(..., label=label)
  # Cut away the label
  temp$children[[1]] <- NULL
  # Cut away the input field (after label is cut, this is position 1 now)
  temp$children[[1]]$children[[2]] <- NULL
  # Remove input group classes (makes button flat on one side)
  temp$children[[1]]$attribs$class <- NULL
  temp$children[[1]]$children[[1]]$attribs$class <- NULL
  temp
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$head(tags$style(".shiny-file-input-progress {display: none}")),
  fileInput2("getdata", label=NULL, buttonLabel="Get Data", placeholder=NULL),
)

server<-function(input, output, session) {
  options(shiny.maxRequestSize=30*1024^2)
  
  observeEvent(input$getdata,{
    dat<-read.csv(input$getdata$datapath)

  })
}

shinyApp(ui,server)


Preferably, I'm looking for either an option to fix the issue that file.choose() triggers RStudio to the front or to have selectFile() default to the working directory. Suggestions for completely alternative approaches are welcome, but so far I have not found something. I did look into shinyFiles, but neither liked the optics nor was it really working when I tried it. From what I understand, it actually also is no longer maintained?
